# Boolean conditions not honored from child component overlay to parent component vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3 where I have the following condition which would display either one or the other button if true or false in the parent component:

```
<template v-if="ammdisabled=false">
                  <v-btn rounded depressed dark large color="red" >
                    <h3>Disable Automation</h3>
                  </v-btn>
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                  <v-btn rounded depressed dark large color="green" > 
                    <h3>Enable Automation</h3>
                  </v-btn>
                </template>
```

The following is the child component which as far as I understand checks for an overlay condition to set the value to true or false:

```
              <AutomatedMarketMaking v-bind:overlay="ammdisabled" ref="amm" />
```

I have the following functions in the child component `AutomatedMarketMaking` which is the entire overlay feature:

```
methods: {
    setOverlay: function(v){
      this.overlay = v
    },
    enable: function(change) {
      this.overlay = change;
      this.$emit("toggleAMM", change)
    },
```

Why does it not get the overlay true or false from the child component and display the buttons accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use === comparison operator in your v-if or just v-if=" !ammdisabled ". Also you cannot change a component property inside the component. They are readonly. Use v-model instead.

```
<template v-if="!ammdisabled">
```

Comment: <AutomatedMarketMaking v-model:overlay="ammdisabled" ref="amm" />

Do you mean like this?

Comment: I am using it the way you said but it still does not read when I disable the overlay. Check this page 

http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/traderview/MORTY/RICK